# How to get specific item from NSArray?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sqlite, nsarray

I have a sqlite database as columns groupno, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday and saturday.
I have retrieved the data using the following code. But this code gives all data in a  single column (for e.g. code skips all previous values in a column and displays final item at the end of the column). However what I need is data from a specific row.

I do not know how to access a single item from NSArray. I would be really grateful for any help.
Thanks.

```
NSArray *info = [dba getinfo];
    for(Getinfo *p in info)
        getinfo.text = [p sunday ];
```

Comment: in that case use normal for loop and  objectAtIndex: method

Comment: Unclear -- are you asking how to reference a database or how to index an array?  (And have you consulted the documentation for either?)

Comment: I am trying to index an array, thanks.

Comment: You index an array as `someArray[indexValue]`.  Or you can use the old-fashioned `[someArray objectAtIndex:indexValue]`.  **If you'd studied the language AT ALL before jumping in coding you'd know this.**

Comment: (Objective-C is not a "learn while doing" language.  You *must* find a reference and study it, at least to get through the basics.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,
I was able to solve the problem by following code to select the specific item,

```
id schedule = [info objectAtIndex:0];
_displayinfo.text = [schedule sunday];
```

Thanks again